# Localized name for default sounds in /System/Library/Sounds

Tags: cocoa, nssound

In the Mail settings one can choose one of the default sounds located at `/System/Library/Sounds`. Playing them is easy, e.g. with `NSSound(named: "Purr")?.play()`, but how can I show a localized name for those sounds as Mail does? I couldn't find any way of getting a localized name. Would I have to manually translate each one to each supported language?

Comment: Mail uses regular localization using `Localizable.strings` files, so that would be a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These translations are stored in these Plist files as of macOS Ventura:

> /System/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/Localizable.loctable

and

> /System/Library/ExtensionKit/Extensions/Sound.appex/Contents/Resources/AlertSounds.loctable

These are dictionaries. You can inspect their contents by adding `.plist` extension to the file name.
I’d either copy the values from these dictionaries or try loading them programmatically at runtime. Note that the paths and contents can change between macOS releases.